# How to disable word-wrap in VS Code on long files

Tags: visual-studio-code, word-wrap

I am making snippets that include full JavaScript libraries, that are minified.

But my problem is, that VScode automatically enables word-wrap for very long lines.

I searched the web, and found people saying that I should just add:

```
"editor.wordWrap": "off",
"editor.stopRenderingLineAfter": -1,
```

To my config. HOWEVER, it only works until I close the tab. If I open the file that has this long line (in this case javascripts.json snippets file), VScode automatically switches that tab to word-wrap: "on" state.

Here is a GIF of what I mean:
https://i.imgur.com/pPkrqMN.gifv

P.S. Can someone embed it for me? <3

I also tried setting these:

```
"editor.maxTokenizationLineLength": 9999999,
"editor.wordWrapColumn": 9999999,
"editor.stopRenderingLineAfter": 9999999,
```

But no luck. I don't care about performance penalties, that many people quote for this issue, I just want full line visible, just like any other IDE.

Is this a bug I have to report to VScode or am I missing some config?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my test environment:

```
Version: 1.37.1 (user setup)
Commit: f06011ac164ae4dc8e753a3fe7f9549844d15e35
Date: 2019-08-15T16:17:55.855Z
Electron: 4.2.7
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17763
```

I didn't find the direct solution. But I found there is an icon on the top right corner, it is a word-wrap icon. Just a click, and you can toggle word-wrap mode.

Another thing, I have tested this setting:

```
"editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
"editor.wordWrapColumn": 10000000
```

and no luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems more and more like a bug I should report..

Answer (score 0):

In my case I noticed it was the **Prettier** extension that was controlling the word wrap.

I simply changed the `Print Width` from the default(80) to 200 and it fixed my problem.

Hope this helps!

[image]